# como cambio el backgroung de un div superior cuando pase sobre el menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy tratando de hacer un menú dinamico que cambie el bg de una pagina.

Pero tengo inconvenientes en que cambie el background si lo hago con el fondo general de la pagina si sale, pero en un div, no.

```js
function menu_id(id){
      document.getElementsByClassName("bg001").className=("fondo"+id);
}
```

```css
body    {
  

font: 18px Arial, Tahoma;
    color:  #b7a687;

}
.bg001   {
 background: url("file:///H:\img1.jpg") 
      no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;

    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: background 0.5s;
       -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: linear;
    -o-transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    height:99vh;
}
.fondo1 {
 background: url("file:///H:\img1.jpg") 
      no-repeat center center fixed;
             background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        
}
.fondo2 {
 background: url("file:///H:\img2.jpg") 
      no-repeat center center fixed;
            background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
}
.fondo3 {
 background: url("file:///H:\img3.jpg") 
      no-repeat center center fixed;
          background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
}
    .fondo4 {
     background: url("file:///H:\img4.jpg") 
          no-repeat center center fixed;
         background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
}
    

    .interior{
        background: #fff;
          position: absolute;
        padding-top: 5px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 284px;
    margin: auto;
    }
    .aqs{
        margin: 15px;
        padding-left: 20px;
      
        line-height: 52px;
        cursor:pointer; cursor: hand;
        transition: margin 1s, background 1s;
    }
    .aqs:hover{
      
    }
       .cli{
            width: 3%;
    background: url("file:///H:\linea.svg")
    center bottom fixed;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 0.5s background 0.5s;
           
    }
   .cli:hover{
        width: 100%;

    }
    span{
        background: #fff   ;
     padding: 15px 20px 15px 10px;
       
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>
<div class="bg001">

<div class="interior">
<div id="1" class="aqs" onmouseenter="menu_id(id)"><div class="cli"><span>item1</span></div></div>
<div id="2" class="aqs" onmouseenter="menu_id(id)"><div class="cli"><span>item2</span></div></div>
<div id="3" class="aqs" onmouseenter="menu_id(id)"><div class="cli"><span>item3</span></div></div>
<div id="4" class="aqs" onmouseenter="menu_id(id)"><div class="cli"><span>item4</span></div></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Te recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de la comunidad y de paso ganar tu primera medalla! También que te pases por  [como elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para así mejorar la tuya y ayuda a los usuarios a responder de manera mas efectiva y precisa. Si tienes cualquier duda tienes toda la info en la sección de [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 1):

Esto debería funcionar para hacer lo que quieres, sólo sustituye lo que sea necesario para que concuerde con tu caso particular

```js
function fondo(id) {
  document.getElementById("fondo").className = "fondo0 fondo" + id;
}
```

```css
.fondo0 {
  background: black;
}

.fondo1 {
  background: blue;
}

.fondo2 {
  background: red;
}

.fondo3 {
  background: brown;
}

.fondo4 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="fondo" class="fondo0">
  <button onmouseenter="fondo(1)">fondo1</button><br><br>
  <button onmouseenter="fondo(2)">fondo2</button><br><br>
  <button onmouseenter="fondo(3)">fondo3</button><br><br>
  <button onmouseenter="fondo(4)">fondo4</button><br><br>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No te funciona porque esto no lo estas haciendo bien:
`onmouseenter="menu_id(id)"`
Estas usando el id del tag como si fuera una variable y eso no funciona asi.
Dejalo como `onmouseenter="menu_id()"` y luego puedes hacer algo asi:

`document.getElementsByClassName("bg001").className=("fondo"+this.id);`

peeero no te va a funcionar porque cambiaras el nombre de la clase y ya no podras volver a seleccionarlo con `getElementsByClassName("bg001")` o sea que lo mejor es que lo selecciones por su id y cambies su clase.

`document.getElementById("bg").className=("fondo"+this.id);`